# Standard android project referencing a maven project - SDK 20.0.1 and ADT 20.0.2 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, maven, eclipse-plugin, adt

After updating to a new SDK 20.0.1 and ADT 20.0.2 my Android project broke at runtime.
Everything seems nice at development time, but when i run i get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exceptions.

I make reference to a Maven project using: Properties > Java Build Path > Projects > Add

Does not fit to me:

- Exporting the dependency does not work (Order and Export menu)
- I don want to build the dependency and put it on libs/ folder

How to fix it?